# How to read the value of propTypes of my Button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jsx

I need a function that would return the `propTypes` and the `defaultProps` of any React Component in order to display a table like this:

[image]

I have created the following function to read the `propTypes` and `defaultProps`

```
function getInfo(component) {
  console.log('propTypes', component.propTypes)
  console.log('defaultProps', component.defaultProps)
}
```

### Reproduction

https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KfXIWlTGcgSo-GeNAFR

### Expected && Result

To log the propTypes and defaultProps

## How about in webpack 2?

I am trying to reproduce the same thing with components that look like this:

```
export class Button extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onSubmitFormLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    changeForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    requestError: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    data: {}
  };
...
}
```

In order for this to work, you need to use the `static` **keyword**

According to [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&code=%20%20class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20static%20propTypes%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20static%20defaultProps%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20%7B%20firstname%3A%20'dka'%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0Afunction%20getInfo(component)%20%7B%0A%20%20console.log('propTypes'%2C%20component.propTypes)%0A%20%20console.log('defaultProps'%2C%20component.defaultProps)%0A%7D%0AgetInfo(Foo)%0A), It should be the exact same thing **but for some reason** I cannot read the `propTypes` but only the `defaultProps` so where do they go ?

Is it Webpack/Babel that removed them ?

Did anyone succeed to read is `propTypes` using this syntax ?

Note: *I wasn't able to reproduce the issue as I didn't find any webpackbin equivalent that allow the `static` keyword*

Comment: It works fine with the class property (`static`). With the `Button` you posted and the `getInfo` of the webpackbin, calling `getInfo(Button)` shows them correctly.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am saying, it work fine in this environment. I am asking why it doesn't work fine in another environment.

Comment: You said that the one with class properties doesn't work with webpack 2, but it does. If you can read one but not the other, you probably have a typo in your code. The Button you posted works perfectly fine.

Comment: @MichaelJungo that's the problem, I have no error in my code and with my coworker we agreed we needed to ask someone. Try cloning this repository. Just install it https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate and try your self, this is almost the configuration I have so there is no reason that you can and I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the repository you linked it is perfectly possible to access `propTypes`. So what could have gone wrong?

There are pretty much two possibilities. The first one is that `component.propTypes` is undefined. And with the boilerplate this is the case when building the app for production (`npm run build`). It uses [babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types](https://github.com/oliviertassinari/babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types) (as seen in its [`package.json`](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/blob/8407cf05c4f1d43ca6c78625b7b8fee7627fdedb/package.json#L70)), which strips out the prop types. As it doesn't happen in development, it's unlikely that this was the experienced behaviour.

The second possibility is that there was an error. It is worth reading the error carefully:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: PropTypes is not defined
```

It says `PropTypes` is not defined, so this can't possibly be `component.propTypes` or the class property declaration. Where is `PropTypes` used?

```
static propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  //      ^ here
  onSubmitFormLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //                   ^ here
  changeForm: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //            ^ here
  requestError: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  //              ^ and here
};
```

Clearly that means you did not import `PropTypes`. To fix it import it:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
```

Alternatively you can use `React.PropTypes` and you don't need to change the import.

Comment: It is because of the remove propTypes plugin. So if I want to read the propTypes, I need to have a build with the plugin disabled, is there a way to disable it just for a single build ?

Comment: No, but that's what build targets are for. Only include the plugin in production.

Comment: Well, it's a distribution build for production `module`. If I want to read it from the documentation app, I need it to be distributed with it's props. I wonder if the plugin is very important for the optimization, I guess **propTypes** are just 20 to 40 octets per components.